# Delegates and datasource not working for UIPopoverListView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, datasource

I have downloaded the UIPopOverListView from github, and pasted in my workspace, then when a button is clicked, the popoverlistview appears, but the delegates and datasource methods are called but not working properly,
When my button is clicked

```
-(void) effectsButtonClicked
{
effectsPopView = [[UIPopoverListView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,150,300,200 )];
effectsPopView.delegate=self;
effectsPopView.datasource=self;
effectsPopView.listView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
[effectsPopView setTitle:@"Effects"];
[effectsPopView show];
}
```

Then my datasouce and delegates are

```
#pragma mark - UIPopOverListView DataSource

- (NSInteger)popoverListView:(UIPopoverListView *)popoverListView
   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 5;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)popoverListView:(UIPopoverListView *)popoverListView
                cellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell * effectsCell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                         reuseIdentifier:identifier];

effectsArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Black and White",@"Sepia",@"Hue",@"Snow",@"Normal", nil];
effectsCell.textLabel.text=[effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
effectsCell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
NSLog(@"%@",effectsArray);
return effectsCell;
}

#pragma mark- UIPopoverList Delegates

- (void)popoverListView:(UIPopoverListView *)popoverListView
 didSelectIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"ROw selected");
}
```

screen shot is

[image]

Can anyone explain, why the datasource and delegates are not working

Answer (score 0):

there are tow ways to connect dataSource
 from 
 (1)add from file owner 
 (2) from interface

Answer (score 0):

It seems that internally `UIPopoverListView` implements `UITableView`. In all the table view data source methods, it is calling the exposed `datasource` methods which you are implementing.

Issue, what I think, is that assignment of `delegate` and `datasource` is happening after the `UITableView` datasource methods get called. There is no mechanism to recall them after `UIPopoverListView` datasource is set. As a workaround you can implement a `reload` method which will just call `reloadData` on the internal table view instance.

```
-(void) reload {
    if(_listView) {
        [_listView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Declare this method in .h file and call it in your code,

```
 -(void) effectsButtonClicked
 {
      effectsPopView = [[UIPopoverListView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,150,300,200 )];
      effectsPopView.delegate=self;
      effectsPopView.datasource=self;
      effectsPopView.listView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
      [effectsPopView setTitle:@"Effects"];
      //Call here before presenting.
      [effectsPopView reload];
      [effectsPopView show];
```

}

This may not be ideal solution, just a workaround. You should file a bug at project's github page so that the original author can provide a fix.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the method like default init in your UIPOpoverListView class
or
you need to reload the table in popoverltstView Show method
- (void)show
{
//reload table here

}